# Codeigniter retaining id in Edit form after validation

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation

I am using same form in view for Edit and Add record in codeigniter view. On adding a new record side, everything is fine.

The problem is with Edit side. Below is my view file.

Main problem is with retaining the ID of the record I am editing. When form validation fails, the ID also gets lost. When ID is lost, the controller does not know which record to edit?

Does someone have a better way to solve this problem.

```
if (isset($add_faq) || isset($edit_faq)) {
$question = isset($faq->question) ? $faq->question : "";
$answer = isset($faq->answer) ? $faq->answer : "";
if (isset($add_faq)) {
    echo "<h4>Add new FAQ</h4>";
    echo form_open('admin/faq/saveNewFaq', 'id="login"');
} else {
    $faqId = isset($faq->id) ? $faq->id : "";
    echo "<h4>Edit FAQ</h4>";
    echo form_open('admin/faq/saveEditFaq', 'id="login"');
    echo '<ul><li>';
    echo form_input('faqId', set_value('faqId', $faqId), 'disabled');
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '<li>';
echo form_label('Question', 'question');
echo form_input('question', set_value('question', $question), 'placeholder="Faq Question"');
echo form_error('question', '<div class="error">', '</div>');
echo '</li>';

echo '<li>';
echo form_label('Answer', 'answer');
echo form_textarea('answer', set_value('answer', $answer), 'placeholder="Faq Answer"');
echo form_error('answer', '<div class="error">', '</div>');
echo '</li>';

echo '<li>';
echo form_submit('submit', 'Add New', 'id = "submit_reg"');
echo '</li></ul>';
echo form_close();
```

Comment: how about storing the id in a session and destroying the session after a successful edit?

Comment: Yes but then that ID becomes empty when the validation fails because the controller is loaded again when validation fails to display the view.

Comment: then add a condition on the session, if session is not empty don't assign a new one. or you could pass the ID on the views and on the hidden input so that when you submit the form you still get it as post value